# jQuery text slider animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this cool script :

http://puaction.com/testimonials/

I want to make the same exact script with jQuery?

Here is my starting point

http://jsfiddle.net/5p79oevx/

html:

```
<div id="testimonials">

    <div class="testimonial">
        &quot;Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text &quot; - <span>Person</span>
    </div>

    <div class="testimonial">
        &quot;Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text &quot; - <span>Person</span>
    </div>

    <div class="testimonial">
        &quot;Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text &quot; - <span>Person</span>
    </div>

    <div class="testimonial">
        &quot;Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text &quot; - <span>Person</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
#testimonials
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.testimonial span
{
    color:red;
}
```

thanks !

Comment: If you want you text to behave like a `<marquee>` (deprecated) there's jQuery Marquee for this : http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#examples .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5p79oevx/61/)**.

This code use **Jquery UI**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
function roll(){
    var curr = 2;
    var count = 4;
    $('#testimonials .testimonial:nth-child(1)').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 500);
    setInterval(function(){
        //console.log('C:'+curr);
        $('#testimonials .testimonial').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);
        $('#testimonials .testimonial:nth-child('+curr+')').delay(750).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 500);
        curr++;
        if(curr == count+1){
            // 5000 - 500 - 750 - 500 = 3250    =>    delay = 3000
            $('#testimonials .testimonial:nth-child(4)').delay(3000).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);
            curr = 1;
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#testimonials
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
.testimonial
{
    display: none;
}
.testimonial span
{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Nice job man! 2 minor tweaks :

1. The last testimonial is not looping back to the first one and it's completely empty...

2. The next testimonial is not going up WITH the current testimonial...

OTHER THAN THAT HIGHLY IMPRESSIVE ! :)

Comment: Yes I know :) that is why I said not 100%... I'll try to fix that to.

Comment: Almost bro! Nice job! :))))))))))))

Comment: Please mark it as correct, if you are happy with answer :)